# How to generate Monero wallet without displaying keys/seed on the screen?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I travel frequently, and many times I need to generate a new wallet while I am in an airport, or another public place. Heck, this question even applies in one's own home, if you are paranoid enough.

All wallets I've tried (including the core), insist on displaying the seed or the private keys on the computer screen, which of course can be captured easily from behind you.

Is there an easy way to generate a Monero wallet, and save the files, without having every bit largely displayed on the screen?

This web page kind of does that: https://moneroaddress.org/. The only problem with that page is that it's an offline wallet, and in order to even view the transactions I need to view/display the keys on the screen in order to copy-paste them in an online wallet.

Comment: DAMN you're paranoid! Generate a wallet in the hotel room or the toilet under a peace of clothing or under a blanket

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `--non-deterministic` flag to monero-wallet-cli, the seed will not be displayed, since there is no seed for these. The secret view key is displayed, but not the secret spend key. This may or may not be enough for your purposes.

If you're on Linux machine (or similar), you can also pipe it to grep, like this:

`./monero-wallet-cli --generate-new-wallet somename --non-deterministic | grep --line-buffered -v ^View\ key:`

Note that you will NOT see the password prompts, so you should know when it's asking for one, and enter it blind when you know it's asking for one.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the shoulder surfing, maybe change text to black on black? (for CLI)
Drag the seed portion off screen?
Memorizing 25 random words in order in a couple seconds is rather hard.  Doubt many cameras can zoom & focus fast enough.

Just make a bunch ahead of time, and peel one off when needed.